# Spring Security 5 and JSF 2.2 Bean authentication

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I have to configure the spring security 5 with jsf,
this bellow code work fine in spring security 4 but when i migrate to version 5 the authentication process is not triggered :

The login form look like this:

```
<h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false">
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" showIcon="false" />
    <div class="ui-fluid">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="#{msg['login.login']}" />
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{userBean.userDTO.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['login.login.required']}" label="#{msg['login.login']}" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msg['login.password']}" />
            <p:password id="password" required="true" feedback="false" label="#{msg['login.password']}" requiredMessage="#{msg['login.password.required']}" />
            <p:spacer />
            <p:commandButton type="submit" value="#{msg['login.btn']}" action="#{userBean.doLogin}" ajax="false" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

JSF Bean :

```
public String doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/login");
    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        logDebug(LOGGER, getPartCodeLoggedPartner(), "Authentification");
        UserSecurity userSecurity = (UserSecurity) ((Authentication) auth).getPrincipal();
        setUserRight(getLoggedUser(), userSecurity);
    }
    return "";
}
```

And the security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /** The utilisateur service. */
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService utilisateurService;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
     * WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.
     * config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // require all requests to be authenticated except for the resources
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**", "/resources/**", "/index.jsp", "/views/login.jsf", "/pages/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // login
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/views/login.jsf").loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").failureUrl("/views/login.jsf?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/views/home.jsf");
        // logout
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/views/login.jsf");
        // not needed as JSF 2.2 is implicitly protected against CSRF
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    /**
     * Md 5 password encoder.
     *
     * @return the message digest password encoder
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageDigestPasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder() {
        return new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5");
    }

    /**
     * Configure global.
     *
     * @param auth
     *            the auth
     * @throws Exception
     *             the exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Setting Service to find User in the database.
        // And Setting PassswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(utilisateurService).passwordEncoder(md5PasswordEncoder());

    }
}
```

when i submit the login form the authentication is not triggered !
did I forget something in this configuration ?

in spring security 4 the action to trigger login and logout is made like this:

```
            ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_login");
            dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

and logout :

```
            ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_logout");
            dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
            context.invalidateSession();
```

i have tried to change j_spring_security_login to login and j_spring_security_logout to logout but not work

Comment: Is `doLogin` called?

Comment: yes the method is called but the authentication is not triggered

Comment: Then I'd say JSF has done its job and it might be a pure spring thing. Btw sort of a strange construction do 'forward' a request in the doLogin method... Is that the common way to combine jsf and spring-security? Are there not more straight-forward ways?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be that the Spring Security 5 filter chain no longer has a default dispatcher mapping for forward. I did not find an easy way to add this mapping in the Java configuration so I ended up using the authenticationProvider directly in the doLogin method to fix it.

replacing:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = ((ServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/login");
requestDispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse());
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

with this:

```
try {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, password ); 
    Authentication authentication = authenticationProvider.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Login failed");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
}

    authentication.isAuthenticated()...
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I stumbled with the same problem with Spring boot security and JSF.

Based on @molholm answer, you just have to declare the filter chain to forward!

Simply put this on your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

And it should do the trick.